# Get the Numbers from r.text

Tags: python, text

I am trying to take the numbers from a code :

```
import requests
import re

payload = {'cityId':3969, 'lbDistricts':599, 'criter':149,'startdate':'2003-01','cmd':'result','areaCode':18439}
url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)


print r.text
```

From this the result returns below, I need Dates and Values individually because I will try to construct a table after. But I could not convert them. Sorry for the long post

```
>{ "output": {"ErrorMesg": null, "resultset": {"record": {"areaid": "599",  "data": [ {"Date": "2003-01", "Value": "43.99" }, {"Date": "2003-02", "Value": "44.19" }, {"Date": "2003-03", "Value": "44.67" }, {"Date": "2003-04", "Value": "45.19" }, {"Date": "2003-05", "Value": "45.98" }, {"Date": "2003-06", "Value": "46.82" }, {"Date": "2003-07", "Value": "47.68" }, {"Date": "2003-08", "Value": "48.59" }, {"Date": "2003-09", "Value": "49.7" }, {"Date": "2003-10", "Value": ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you are retrieving via the web request is in the [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

1. You first need to convert the json data to a data structure python understands. The [python json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) would serve you the purpose.
2. Once you convert the json data to a nested dictionary structure, you need to navigate through the data and retrieve the `(date, value)` dictionary pair.
3. Then you need to discard the key and fetch the values. The resultant data should be a list of data value tuples

### Example Code

```
import json
data = json.loads(r.text)
data = map(dict.values, data[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
for row in data:
    print '{:10}{:10}'.format(*row)
```

### Example Output

```
2003-01   43.99     
2003-02   44.19     
2003-03   44.67     
2003-04   45.19     
2003-05   45.98
...............
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

Assuming that you're trying to extract the "Date" and "Value" fields from that blob, you can do:

```
import json # since this thing seems to be returning json back to you

data = json.loads(r.text) # turn it into a python dict
#loop through all the data you care about 
for record in data["output"]["resultset"]["record"]["data"]: 
    print record["Date"], record["Value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is  json so use `r.json()` not `r.text` and access whatever information you need using the keys:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

for d in r.json()["output"]['resultset']['record']["data"]:
    print(d)

{u'Date': u'2003-01', u'Value': u'43.99'}
{u'Date': u'2003-02', u'Value': u'44.19'}
{u'Date': u'2003-03', u'Value': u'44.67'}
{u'Date': u'2003-04', u'Value': u'45.19'}
{u'Date': u'2003-05', u'Value': u'45.98'}
{u'Date': u'2003-06', u'Value': u'46.82'}
{u'Date': u'2003-07', u'Value': u'47.68'}
{u'Date': u'2003-08', u'Value': u'48.59'}
{u'Date': u'2003-09', u'Value': u'49.7'}
{u'Date': u'2003-10', u'Value': u'50.7'}
{u'Date': u'2003-11', u'Value': u'51.36'}
{u'Date': u'2003-12', u'Value': u'52.16'}
{u'Date': u'2004-01', u'Value': u'53.12'}
{u'Date': u'2004-02', u'Value': u'54.17'}
{u'Date': u'2004-03', u'Value': u'54.86'}
{u'Date': u'2004-04', u'Value': u'55.58'}
{u'Date': u'2004-05', u'Value': u'56.55'}
{u'Date': u'2004-06', u'Value': u'57.69'}
{u'Date': u'2004-07', u'Value': u'58.89'}
{u'Date': u'2004-08', u'Value': u'60.01'}
{u'Date': u'2004-09', u'Value': u'61.16'}
{u'Date': u'2004-10', u'Value': u'62.03'}
{u'Date': u'2004-11', u'Value': u'62.72'}
{u'Date': u'2004-12', u'Value': u'63.5'}
{u'Date': u'2005-01', u'Value': u'64.47'}
{u'Date': u'2005-02', u'Value': u'65.46'}
.......................................
```